# Retrieve data from csv file in BigQuery without using Tables

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I'm trying to look for retrieval of Data/Select Data from CSV file directly without using Tables in BigQuery ( Google Cloud Platform) . Is the retrieval possible?

Comment: you can use "bq extract" to extract them to google cloud bucket using cli and then later use gsutil to download locally

Comment: Thanks for the Inputs

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [External Data Sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources). For example you can [create pseudo table referencing csv file in Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#creating_and_querying_a_permanent_external_table):
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the  Solution, but looking for directly reading CSV file without creating native tables. Is it possible?

Comment: There is an option [not to create permanent table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#temporary-tables). Not sure if there are some other options besides that.